# Honda CVT Multimatic Gearbox oil-change frequency

Tags: honda, oil-change, gear-oil

I'm planning to buy a 1999 Honda Civic with Multimatic Gearbox and the current owner claims that he needs oil changes after every 7,500 Kms. But when I read about it most suggest the oil change only requires after 15,000 Kms. Anyone can clarify this to me?

Comment: Did they give a reason why?

Answer (score 3):

He probably meant CVT oil/transmission oil. Honda CVT oil needs replacing more often once car has driven a lot of K's. Considering its 1999, i assume it will have more than 150K KMs', so in that case he may be right in mentioning replacement every 7500KM. 
CVT's need to be taken care of unlike auto transmission cars.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he meant the engine oil every 7500kms? Transmission oil on the other hand, lasts a lot longer than engine oil. Heavy city usage, 15k max. Primarily highway, 30k max.

Comment: unfortunately not. he was referring to gear oil specifically :(